# debug error: stack around the variable 's' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio

edit(fixed): so the error seems to appear because writing a 20 character array will add \0 as a character and become a 21 character array.

I'm trying to detect a char c and remove it from a string char[20] s, but if I wrote a string s of 20 characters exactly, the debug error pops but the code works fine. why does it happen?

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void resultt(char c, char s[]) {
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (*s == c) {
            strcpy(s,(s+1));
            continue;
        }
        s++;
    }
}

void mainn() {
    char c; char s[20];
    cout << "enter a string : ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "enter the character : "; cin >> c;
    resultt(c, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

I call that function like this `resultt(c,s)` and `cout<<s` at last.

Comment: *"The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap."* https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: Please show a [mre] but at a guess you don't have enough space in `s` for the string and the null terminator

Comment: *the code works fine*. No, the code *appears to* work fine. And then when you least expect it, the airplane drops out of the sky

Comment: `void mainn()` probably a typo, and if so the return type is incorrect. `main` always returns `int`. Anything else is non-Standard.

Comment: Does this "string s of 20 characters exactly" include the null terminator? Bear in mind that a string stored in a `char[20]` array can have a maximum of *19* characters, followed by `'\0'`.

Comment: @user4581301 but why tho? if i wrote "qwertyuiopqwertyuiop" which is 20 char and remove any letter it gets removed

Comment: @jjramsey oh okay, didn't include it at first

Comment: A program can break relatively silently and the error may lurk undetected for years before something visibly wrong happens. In your case `char s[20];` will hold 19 characters and the null terminator. It cannot safely hold 20 characters. Before C++20 `cin >> s;` will read until it finds a whitespace character no matter where that whitespace character is with respect to the size of the buffer. Crom only knows what it writes over after it breaches the buffer. As of C++20 `cin >> s;` will infer the size of the array and stop before the program breaks.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT alright!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error seems to appear because writing a 20 character array will add \0 as a character and become a 21 character array. by writing for example `qwertyuiopqwertyuiop` which is 20 characters, there won't be enough space in the array for the \0 character, so you should write a 19 character word (or less) or increase the array to 21